# An occurs when build the flutter Apk

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, build, apk

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter _tools\Gradle\Flutter. Gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app : Compile Flutter Build Release'.

> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --Stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             59.7s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

Comment: Check if you're using outdated dependencies in pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Running your project without sound null safety.

If you want to run your project with `--no-sound-null-safety`, you add this line your `main.dart` file in the top (first line) with a comment:

```
// @dart=2.9
```

then run your project.